# Curl with if statement

Tags: shell, if-statement, curl, sh

Can you help me to resolve this code?? Server ip is masked for obvious reasons.

```
#!/bin/sh
command=$(curl -sI https://*******.com | grep Server)
echo "$command"
reply="Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)"
echo "$reply"


if [ "$command" = "$reply" ]; then
  echo "It works!"
fi
```

Info I have caught:

- I don't get errors in ShellCheck. I know that `$command` equals to `$reply` but it doesn't answer me with "It works!" in anyway
- I tested too to use `/usr/bin/curl`
- With other commands in `$command` it works, but with `curl -sI` it doesn't and I have all installed. (If I execute the command in terminal, it works.) I think curl is the problem.

Comment: (OT: What made you add those extra backticks in the question? I’ve seen those a lot lately but I don’t understand why. Is the question editor broken?)

Comment: Could it be a carriage return in `$command` not present in `$reply`? What do `printf %s "${command}" | od` and `printf %s "${reply}" | od` show?

Comment: First of all, you are retrieving headers, and there's no warranty all web servers will provide you with `Server`. Also, I'd advise you to use `grep server -i` - some servers might return headers in lower case (try `curl -sI https://example.com`). In any case - please provide output of `curl -sI https://*******.com | grep Server`.

Comment: **printf %s "${command}" | od** 

0000000 062523 073162 071145 020072 063556 067151 027570 027061
0000020 034061 030056 024040 061125 067165 072564 006451
0000036


**printf %s "${reply}" | od** 
0000000 062523 073162 071145 020072 063556 067151 027570 027061
0000020 034061 030056 024040 061125 067165 072564 000051
0000035

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs the output of "curl -sI https://*****.com | grep Server" is indeed "Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)"

Comment: @Manuel So the variables aren’t equal then.

Comment: @Biffen Thanks for the help, but the command output is the same of $reply as text, how can I equate them??

Comment: @Manuel They are demonstrably _not_ the same, they just _look like_ they are. Some kind of cleanup of `$command` or some fuzzier matching could work. It depends on what it is you’re _actually_ trying to do.

Comment: @Biffen I needed this code to send a certain link in case there is a certain web server

Comment: @Manuel Wouldn’t something like `if curl -sI https://….com | grep -iq '^server: nginx/1\.18\.0' ; then …` suffice then?

Comment: @Biffen thanks you so mutch! It works. If you post it as an answer in addition to the comment I give the green check

Answer (score 1):

The only issue I can think of is the termination of strings. Quick test:

```
#!/bin/sh

command=$(curl -sI https://example.com | grep server -i)
echo "$command"
reply="server: ECS (dcb/7F83)"

echo $command | xxd
echo $reply | xxd

if [ "$command" = "$reply" ]; then
  echo "It works!"
else
  echo "Of course it does not work."
fi
```

...shows following:

```
server: ECS (dcb/7FA6)
00000000: 7365 7276 6572 3a20 4543 5320 2864 6362  server: ECS (dcb
00000010: 2f37 4641 3629 0d0a                      /7FA6)..
00000000: 7365 7276 6572 3a20 4543 5320 2864 6362  server: ECS (dcb
00000010: 2f37 4638 3329 0a                        /7F83).
Of course it does not work.
```

See extra `0d`? That's a carriage return. You need to strip all this stuff before comparing it:

```
command =$(curl -sI https://*******.com | grep Server | tr -d '\r')
```

Comment: it was useful, but in the end the solution to the problem was:

if curl -sI https://….com | grep -iq '^server: nginx/1\.18\.0' ; then …

as https://stackoverflow.com/users/418066/biffen reported in the comments